# Dictionaries with one key and two values To CSV

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary of the following form

```
>>> {'1' : [V3210 , 234567 ,1235675 , 23], '2' : [v3214 , 5678 ,65879 ,89} , ...}
```

How to write dictionary into csv form, like so:

```
1    V3210    234567    12345675    23
2    v3214    5678      65879       89
```

I tried:

```
for key, value in van.iteritems():
   w.writerow([key, value])
```

Comment: That is not valid syntax, presumably you meant `,89]` (square bracket) at the end. But what have you tried? What errors did you get?

Comment: please look above @roganjosh

Comment: what is w.writerow()?

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

van =  {'1' : ['V3210' , 234567 ,1235675 , 23], '2' : ['v3214' , 5678 ,65879 ,89]}

with open('some_name.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    my_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t',
                           quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for key, val in van.items():
        my_writer.writerow([key] + val)
```

---

`some_name.csv`:

> ```
> 1 V3210   234567  1235675 23
> 2 v3214   5678    65879   89
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt was super-close. You need to "unpack" the values stored in the list using `*` (the "splat" operator):

```
for key, value in van.iteritems():
   w.writerow([key, *value])
```

I *think* this should work in 2.7. Note that Python 2.x comes to the end of its life within a year so it's time to think of moving to Python 3.

If it doesn't work, you can concatenate the lists:

```
w.writerow([key] + value)
```

The bottom line is that `writerow` expects a 1D list to represent that row. In the concatenation case, we have to enclose `key` in a list first. Otherwise we can just unpack the `value` list items into the main list.